# Importing Intellij / Android Studio Local History to VCS

Tags: version-control, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have been learning Android using Android Studio and developing outside of any VCS. I would like to put the code under VCS and would also like to import my local history into the VCS, preserving my learning steps.

Is there some built-in support for this?

Is there someway of converting or saving Android Studio/IntelliJ Local History to VCS History?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such way. It is possible to write a plugin for that, but the value of this would still be quite limited, for two reasons. First, VCS commits usually have meaningful human-written descriptions, and local history snapshots don't. Second, local history snapshots are usually made at a much higher frequency than VCS commits, so the commit history would be extremely cluttered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am fully aware of your first & second point. As I stated earlier, it is purely for tracking my learning progress. I will write a plugin. I  will mark this as an answer

Comment: But it prevents any kind of software-reasoned data loss and if your boss asks why you need so long for bug XY, you can show him the size of your local history changes (compared to maybe other stuff). So you/he has hard evidence that you actually did do something in case of a lawsuit. Sorry for the necro btw..